# How to get groupId from version variable name

Tags: bash, shell, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I am having a pom file which has the dependency in such a way that,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipsex</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${equinox.servlet.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I just wanted to grab the groupId by providing the version variable `equinox.http.servlet.version`. This should be done using a shell script.

Is there any mvn commands available or any other way I can obtain this.

Comment: Why do you like to do that? What kind of problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: There's a tool called `xmlstartlet` that's useful for parsing XML files, it may be helpful for this.

Comment: @khmarbaise the problem I am trying to solve is cannot be disclosed. But the only thing I want is to obtain the corressponding groupId whenever I give the version variable name. 
For example, if I give `equinox.servlet.version`, I should have to obtain the groupId as `org.eclipsex`